# href issue in ie7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, href

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wrong extraction of .attr(“href”) in IE7 vs all other browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593174/wrong-extraction-of-attrhref-in-ie7-vs-all-other-browsers)

I trying to get the url from href called /resource.html, but when i tried to copy the same url to a variable using jquery the variable is have the absolute url only in ie7. The other browser including ie8 showing fine but have issue only in ie7.

```
href="/resource.html"
```

---

```
var childid = $(this).attr("href");
alert(chilid);
```

shows only in IE7 as...

```
http://mysite.com/resource.html
```

but in other browsers it shows as

```
/resource.html
```

Comment: what else `childid` and `chilid` the alert string is not the string you set

Answer (score 1):

so ie is right.

try

```
var childid = $(this).attr("href").replace(/^.*(?=\/)/, '')
```

Comment: But if i have a bigger url such as http://mysite.com/about/myicons/resource.html, so how can i truncate the whole url except /resource.html?

Answer (score 0):

Just parse the rest out:

```
if (childid.substring(0,7)==="http://") {
    childid = '/'+childid.split('/').slice(3).join('/'); 
}
```