# FadeIn after FadeOut

Tags: jquery

I can't figure it out why my div won't fadeIn after FadeOut finishes.

Heres my Html:

```
<div class="header-container">
    <header class="wrapper clearfix">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#tab1">Section 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#tab2">Section 2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </header>
</div>

<div class="main-container">
    <div class="main wrapper clearfix">

        <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                    <p>I'm in Section 1.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
                    <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 2.</p>
                </div>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- #main -->
</div> <!-- #main-container -->
```

My JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nav-tabs a').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var href = $(this).attr('href'); // Select first tab
        $('.tab-pane').fadeOut(1000,function(){
            $(href).fadeIn(1000);
        });
    });

});
```

My Css

```
.tab-pane {
    display: none;
}
```

I made a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyDevv/hKq2K/1/

I made it simple as possible...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Works for me. Something else wrong there?

Comment: Which browser are you using? I can't replicate the issue with your jsFiddle

Comment: This works for me too. You should `console.log()` this line: `var href = $(this).attr('href');` and check that you are getting the correct value.

Comment: I've had an issue with IE7 returning the absolute path instead of simply the anchor. As the others have stated, which browser are you testing in?  IE7 issue: IE7 .attr() bug references: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11129 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593174/wrong-extraction-of-attrhref-in-ie7-vs-all-other-browsers

Comment: I'm using chrome..and never had this problem.
Not using any javascripts beside jquery.1.9.1.min and modernizer, so class tab-pane couldn't be a problem.
Has css i have normalizer for reset and my main.css cleaned only containing body styles, not using any framework.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This will output the desired result you are expecting:

```
 $('.tab-pane').fadeOut(1000).promise().done(function(){
     $(href).fadeIn(1000);
 });
```

`.promise()` ensures to complete the `fadeOut()` first then when it completes `.done()` executes.

#### [DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hKq2K/3/)

Comment: Was searching for this since a year I think ':(

Comment: Awesome solution! Worked like a charm!!

Answer (score 1):

You are using the common class name .tab-pane to animate the fadeout that seems to be the issue try to take advantage of the ".active" class you have

Try this js

```
$('.nav-tabs a').click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var href = $(this).attr('href'); // Select first tab
     // select the active tab then remove the active class name then do the fade out
     $('.tab-pane.active').removeClass("active").fadeOut('slow',function(){
          $(href).addClass("active").fadeIn(1000);
     });
});
```

JS Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hKq2K/2/

Answer (score 1):

Taking advantage of the user's hook: [Jai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1059101/jai)

If you want it to not work if the tab content is already open use:

> **[.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)**

```
$('.nav-tabs a').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var href = $(this).attr('href'); // Select first tab
        $('.tab-pane').not(href).fadeOut(1000).promise().done(function(){
            $(href).fadeIn(1000);
        });
    });
```

[**DEMO jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hKq2K/35/)

Sorry my english, i is from another nationality. =]