# JavaScript runtime error in IE: Unable to get property 'top'

Tags: javascript, jquery

***Question Background:***

I have a navbar that 'smoothly scrolls' to a corresponding div based on the selected items id.

***The Issue:***

In Chrome and FireFox there are no issues, when I try and select an option from the navbar in IE (version 11) the following JavaScript error is showing:

```
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'top' of undefined or null reference
```

***The code:***

This is the JS code for the Smooth Scroll:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#nav .navbar-nav li>a').on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var sectionID = $(this).attr("href");
            scrollToID(sectionID, 750);
        });

        function scrollToID(id, speed) {
            var offSet = 70;

            **ERROR LINE -  IN IE ONLY:**
            var targetOffset = $(id).offset().top - offSet;

            $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: targetOffset }, speed);
        }
    });
</script>
```

**EDIT - ADDED HTML MARKUP:**

**Navbar:**

```
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" id="nav">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand logo"><img src="~/images/mE.png" id="logo" alt="Logo"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#myCarousel">Projects</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#Welcome">Welcome</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#features">Workplace, Education, Development</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#About">About Me</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#Location">Location</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

**Div ID:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 mePadding">
        <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">

          /*CODE*/

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I do not understand how the 'top' property can be null or empty when this code works fine on Chrome?

****EDIT 2 - Added new JavaScript code:****

After some more invesigation the error is being causied because of this line:

```
      var sectionID = $(this).attr("href");
```

This is returning an 'undefined' property for 'sectionID'.

I have modified my code to implement 'data-id' attributes on the dropdown list:

```
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#" data-id="myCarousel">Projects</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" data-id="Welcome">Welcome</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" data-id="features">Workplace, Education, Development</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" data-id="About">About Me</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" data-id="Location">Location</a></li>
```

The JavaScript smooth scroll now looks like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#nav .navbar-nav li>a').on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var sectionID = $(this).data('data-id');
            console.log('ID:'+sectionID);
            scrollToID('#' + sectionID, 750);
        });

        function scrollToID(id, speed)
        {
            //alert('SectionID is: ' + id);
            var offSet = 70;
            var obj = $(id).offset();
            var targetOffset = $(id).offset().top - offSet;
            $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: targetOffset }, speed);
        }
    });
```

***If I hardcode a div ID for example '#myCarosuel' then this works perfectly i.e:***

```
    scrollToID('#myCarosuel, 750);
```

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @dejakob <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Just to throw something at the wall, have you tried adding parenthesis to top? Like "$(id).offset().top()"?

Comment: @trnelson thanks for your comment. I tried this but Top is a property rather than a method.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593174/wrong-extraction-of-attrhref-in-ie7-vs-all-other-browsers for possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

With the HTML code you give, your script **works** for the "Projects" item, even in IE (11). However it fails on the other items ("Welcome", ...) with the error message you mention. I guess that one or several of your id is incorrect: check that "Welcome", "features", "About" and "Location" exist in your page (pay attention to id case as well).

As I have written earlier, `offset()` may return null if applied to an incorrect selector.

Comment: @ M. Page thanks for your reply. I understand what you're saying but am cofused why it works perfectly fine in Chrome and FireFox but in I.E the id cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem a few times with IE (so frustrating). Without looking at your CSS, the main cause of this (that I found) is that it cannot find the height/positioning of the parent element. If IE cannot find it, it automatically searches for the 'body'( or 'html') tag positioning. This happens especially when using relative positioning.

Thus, make sure you have all of the parent divs height/positioning defined. Another possible solution is to define the  tag positioning.

Hope this helps!

P.S. Updating with your CSS might help.

Comment: I have added an Edit2 section to show where the error is occurring in the JavaScript - if I hardcode a div ID then the issue does not happen. Its incredibly frustrating indeed!

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading jQuery may fix the problem.  See **[Wrong extraction of .attr("href") in IE7 vs all other browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593174/wrong-extraction-of-attrhref-in-ie7-vs-all-other-browsers)** for the reason it fails.

Your DIV has id `myCarousel`, but `sectionID` may look like this in IE: `http://example.com/myCarousel`.  Therefore, the DIV cannot be targeted using your original code and your version of jQuery.

If you don't want to upgrade jQuery, this may get you going:

```
var sectionID = '#'+($(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];
```