# href && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, '') in bootstrap modal commented as "strip for ie7", what does this line do for ie7?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am just wondering what goods does this line do for IE7? This code snippet is from bootstrap modal source code.

```
var $target = $($this.attr('data-target') || (href && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, ''))) // strip for ie7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until IE8 there was a "feature" in IE's implementation of `getAttribute()`

If you have an `<a>` tag like this

```
<a href="#anchor">link</a>
```

and you are using `element.getAttribute('href')` IE7 returns the absolute path - `http://example.com/index.html#anchor` while other browsers just returns `#anchor`.

The regex in bootstrap takes care of this - it removes anything before `#`.

---

Update. See also this *very* old question in SO (oct 2009!) -> [**Wrong extraction of .attr(“href”) in IE7 vs all other browsers?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1593174/1407478) with various suggestions of how to solve the problem. Twitter Bootstraps solution is far better, in my opinion.