# Boostrap Carousel Scroll clashing with JS page scroller

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am using a JS script that offsets page content from depth of the Nav, however this is interfering with my page scroll (using the id as anchors) -  I have no idea how to correct this and am not clued up on JS. Any help will be appreciated.

THIS IS MY JS:

```
    function scroll_if_anchor(href) {
    href = typeof(href) == "string" ? href : $(this).attr("href");

    // You could easily calculate this dynamically if you prefer
    var mq = window.matchMedia( "(max-width: 991px)" );
        if (mq.matches) {
            var fromTop = 0;
        }
        else {
            var fromTop = 130;
        }

    // If our Href points to a valid, non-empty anchor, and is on the same page (e.g. #foo)
    // Legacy jQuery and IE7 may have issues: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1593174
    if(href.indexOf("#") == 0) {
        var $target = $(href);

        // Older browser without pushState might flicker here, as they momentarily
        // jump to the wrong position (IE < 10)
        if($target.length) {
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $target.offset().top - fromTop });
            if(history && "pushState" in history) {
                history.pushState({}, document.title, window.location.pathname + href);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

THIS IS MY HTML

```
    <div id="carousel1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

       <?php 
           $loop = new WP_Query(array(
                'post_type' => 'banner', 'orderyby' => 'post_id', 'order' => 'ASC', 
                'posts_per_page' => 1 
            )); 
           while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : 
           $loop->the_post();
        ?>

   <div class="item active">
     <?php the_post_thumbnail('full');?>
       </div><!-- item active -->
    <?php 
   endwhile; 
   wp_reset_postdata();
  ?>

      <?php 
           $loop = new WP_Query(array(
                'post_type' => 'banner', 'orderyby' => 'post_id', 'order' => 'ASC', 
                'posts_per_page' => 10, 
                'offset' => 1 
            )); 
           while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : 
           $loop->the_post();
      ?>

   <div class="item">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('full');?>
   </div><!-- item -->

    <?php 
       endwhile; 
       wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>  


  </div> <!-- CAROUSEL inner -->

  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel1" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a><a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel1" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>

  </div> <!-- CAROUSEL -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Enable Carousel Controls
    $(".left").click(function(){
        $("#carousel1").carousel("prev");
    });
    $(".right").click(function(){
        $("#carousel1").carousel("next");
    });

});
```