# Why is "scrollTop" function not working correctly on live site but works on local host?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

This is a #id link to one page:
This is the #id link to another:

I have WP Rocket Installed, have tried to disable the JS settings but it didn't work either.
I am a novice so your advise is much appreciated.

```js
// PAGE SCROLLER
// PUSHES ANCHOR BELOW DEPTH OF NAVBAR

(function($){
  $(document).ready(function () {

        $(document).on('click','.navbar-collapse.in',function(e) {
            if( $(e.target).is('a') && $(e.target).attr('class') != 'dropdown-toggle' ) {
                $(this).collapse('hide');
            }
        });

        function scroll_if_anchor(href) {
            href = typeof(href) == "string" ? href : $(this).attr("href");

                if (screen.width <= 320) {
                var fromTop = 120;
                } else if (screen.width <= 768) {
                var fromTop = 124;
                } else {
                var fromTop = 90;
                }


            // If our Href points to a valid, non-empty anchor, and is on the same page (e.g. #foo)
            // Legacy jQuery and IE7 may have issues: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1593174
            if(href.indexOf("#") == 0) {
                var $target = $(href);

                // Older browser without pushState might flicker here, as they momentarily
                // jump to the wrong position (IE < 10)
                if($target.length) {
                    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $target.offset().top - fromTop });
                    if(history && "pushState" in history) {
                        history.pushState({}, document.title, window.location.pathname + href);
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // When our page loads, check to see if it contains and anchor
        scroll_if_anchor(window.location.hash);

        // Intercept all anchor clicks

          $("body").on("click", "a", scroll_if_anchor);

  });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to check the error `$ is not a function` (https://prnt.sc/12ald0n) and need to solve it. For better example you can take reference from here https://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/ to scroll top functionality.

Comment: Thank You, Its sorted.